# Change from ScrollView to FlatList in react native

Tags: javascript, scrollview

I'm going to make a todolist app.
On the main page, to show the task of todolist,
I used scrollview, but I want to change it to FlatList.

```js
<ScrollView width = {width-20}>
            {Object.values(tasks).map(item => (
               <Task key = {item.id} item={item} deleteTask={_deleteTask} 
               toggleTask={_toggleTask} updateTask={_updateTask}/>
           ))} 
         </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Flatlist
[More info here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist)

```
<FlatList
     data={Object.values(tasks)}
     keyExtractor={(item)=>item?.id}
     renderItem={({item})=><Task key = {item.id} item={item} deleteTask={_deleteTask} toggleTask={_toggleTask} updateTask={_updateTask}/>}
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of performance, I recommend using the variation when we avoid inline functions.
If you want to know more how to optimize React native FlatList performance: https://codingislove.com/optimize-react-native-flatlist-performance/

```
const renderItem = ({item})=><Task item={item} deleteTask={_deleteTask} toggleTask={_toggleTask} updateTask={_updateTask}/>;
const keyExtractor = (item) => item.id;

return (
  <Flatlist
   data={Object.values(tasks)}
   renderItem={renderItem}
   keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
  />
);
```